# Adding a background image to a site

Tags: html, css, sass

Just a heads up that I **am not** good at using html and css or anything webdev based. However, because I wanted a portfolio website to host my projects I followed a tutorial online and basically copy/pasted and adjusted it to suit me. The website itself has 4 sections: home, about me, projects and contact me.

I want to add an image as a background **only** for the home section but when I tried to add the background attribute to the body or to the section itself when refreshing I see it for a second then it disappears and a solid color takes place. So maybe it needs a change in the css file ? no clue.

Any advice or guidance ? I can't quite provide code here since I don't even know which one to provide but relevant things:

1. In the index.html file the home section starts at line 25.
2. the image I want is in the img subfolder and called banner.png

github repo: `https://github.com/Armonia1999/Portfolio`

website itself: `https://armonia1999.github.io/Portfolio/`

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: How about `.header-content {
    background-image: url(https://armonia1999.github.io/Portfolio/img/banner.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you ! I am not familiar with css or html thats why I didnt figure out how to do it :/  but now I tried and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the path into the background style attribute for the `#home` element

```css
#home {
  background: url("img/banner.png");
}
```